# Is there a numpy function to get the sum of sub matrices?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to get an array which is the sum of the sub matrices in an array.

For example, lets say we have a 3x3 matrix, where each item contains a 2x2 sub matrix:

```
matrix = np.array([[[[1,2],[3,4]],     [[5,6],[7,8]],     [[9,10],[11,12]]],
                   [[[13,14],[15,16]], [[17,18],[19,20]], [[21,22],[23,24]]],
                   [[[25,26],[27,28]], [[29,30],[31,32]], [[33,34],[35,36]]]])
```

which looks like:

```
[[[[ 1  2]
   [ 3  4]]

  [[ 5  6]
   [ 7  8]]

  [[ 9 10]
   [11 12]]]


 [[[13 14]
   [15 16]]

  [[17 18]
   [19 20]]

  [[21 22]
   [23 24]]]


 [[[25 26]
   [27 28]]

  [[29 30]
   [31 32]]

  [[33 34]
   [35 36]]]]
```

One way to get the answer is using list comprehension

```
ans = [ [ np.sum(sub_matrices) for sub_matrices in row ] for row in matrix ]
```

which will be:

```
[[10, 26, 42], [58, 74, 90], [106, 122, 138]]
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to get this result.  Maybe using some numpy function built in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) which is faster in this case than conventional `sum`:

```
np.einsum('ijkl->ij',matrix)

array([[ 10,  26,  42],
       [ 58,  74,  90],
       [106, 122, 138]])
```

Comment: It really is faster.

Comment: @klim Yes, it is.

Comment: Seriously, `einsum` is magic. Is there any place you would recommend (besides the official documentation) for reading up on it? I would never have thought of using it here.

Comment: I am surprised that `einsum` is faster than `.sum(axis=(2,3))` even in this case where no temporaries are involved.

Comment: Sorry still trying to get familiar with einsum.  Is it true that i and j is the rows and cols of the 3x3, and k and l is the rows and cols for the 2x2 matrix?  And since k and l are omitted on the output side, we sum those together? Thanks for the very efficient answer btw.

Comment: @user1179317 Yes, and `einsum` is a pretty complicated function and it is not easy to master. Please check this [`link`](http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) and read the docs link provided in the answer and check its different functionalities to get familiar.

Comment: This `einsum` speed up is nice, but hardly ground breaking (it's not even 2x).  It's advantage decreases with array size, and may even be reversed for some combinations of dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.sum` twice:

```
>>> matrix.sum(axis=2).sum(axis=2)
array([[ 10,  26,  42],
       [ 58,  74,  90],
       [106, 122, 138]])
```

Or, more elegantly, as suggested by @hpaulj, you can simply pass a tuple to the `axis` argument:

```
>>> matrix.sum(axis=(2,3))
array([[ 10,  26,  42],
       [ 58,  74,  90],
       [106, 122, 138]])
```

Comment: `arr.sum(axis=(2,3))`

Comment: @hpaulj ahhh yes.